# Are there still some global locks in mongodb 2.6.3

Tags: mongodb

I have a replica set with 3 servers (QuadCore, 64 GB RAM, SSD - HW-Raid).

The most queries are typically very fast, for example a simple query {ShortKey: "ABC"} on a small collection with 176 documents, each of them very small. The query takes about 1ms in most cases but sometimes the execution time is very high.

The profiler shows that it waits very long for a lock. What I dont understand is that the lock percentage for this db is about 2%. So the question is: Is there any global locking (e.g. for replication) and what can I do to improve it?

```
{
    "op" : "query",
    "ns" : "bls_read.CompanySet",
    "query" : {
      "ShortKey" : "ABC"
    },
    "ntoskip" : 0,
    "nscanned" : 148,
    "nscannedObjects" : 148,
    "keyUpdates" : 0,
    "numYield" : 1,
    "lockStats" : {
      "timeLockedMicros" : {
        "r" : NumberLong(874),
        "w" : NumberLong(0)
      },
      "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
        "r" : NumberLong(4330712),
        "w" : NumberLong(14774)
      }
    },
    "nreturned" : 1,
    "responseLength" : 441,
    "millis" : 4298,
    "execStats" : {
      "type" : "LIMIT",
      "works" : 149,
      "yields" : 1,
      "unyields" : 1,
      "invalidates" : 0,
      "advanced" : 1,
      "needTime" : 148,
      "needFetch" : 0,
      "isEOF" : 1,
      "children" : [{
          "type" : "COLLSCAN",
          "works" : 149,
          "yields" : 1,
          "unyields" : 1,
          "invalidates" : 0,
          "advanced" : 1,
          "needTime" : 148,
          "needFetch" : 0,
          "isEOF" : 0,
          "docsTested" : 148,
          "children" : []
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: MongoDB holds the write lock while applying oplog entries. Read about [index prefetching](http://goo.gl/pA0WSF).

But some lock time while synching is quite OK, not fine but...
I suggest you to turn on [profiler](http://goo.gl/SD4kdV) and see what happens on queries.

Also don't forget to use appropriate [write concern](http://goo.gl/6nwREh) for complicated and unimportant writes.

Be sure you use enough RAM, limit oplog size, and once again, be sure your queries [hit only RAM](http://goo.gl/ENV6ql)

Comment: Hi, the server has 64GB, the data size is 20gb and 24gb is in use. So is shouldnt be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Its plausible your queries are hitting the primary when it could -- depending on the system requirements - hit the secondaries.

Consider changing the [read preference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/) for your queries to `Secondary` or `secondaryPreferred` from the default, `Primary`.

> **By default, an application directs its read operations to the primary member** in a replica set. Reading from the primary guarantees
>   that read operations reflect the latest version of a document.
>   However, by distributing some or all reads to secondary members of the
>   replica set, you can improve read throughput or reduce latency for an
>   application that does not require fully up-to-date data.

Comment: I have forgotten to add that I use Nearest as readpreference. The Service is Running on the same machines, so the queries should be well distributed.

Comment: nearest is likely based on network (ping ms) not cpu metrics. try "secondary" and you'll never hit primary during a write.

Comment: I know, sometimes there are no writes for days on this database, so the writes shouldn't affect the performance at all. This is the point I don't understand.

Comment: you have a rs that hasn't written for days -- yet is periodically slow. a replica set updates itself every 2 seconds or so. that must/should (?) be written to a mongo collection, and lock the db. however, seems like a very unreasonable time. timeAcquiringMicros(4330712). are the machines in a vpn? are they using ip or dns. check etc/hosts etc. print out the names on rs.status(). ping it by those names.